# PeekMessage TranslateMessage DispatchMessage. Is there a way to do this natively in .NET without EXTERN?

Tags: c#, .net, dicom

I'm working on upgrading an older project which uses this mecahnism for a DICOM service. I'm using leadtools. They're example code https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/di/dicomassociate.html

Seems to require extenns into User32.DLL and I'm trying to figure out if there's a newer better way to accomplish this in .NET?

Any ideas?

Comment: That is what Application.DoEvents() does.  Whether it is "better" is debatable, the notorious re-entrancy problems it can cause are no different from the problems that code can cause.  Maybe it dates back to the classic ASP days.  I'd recommend replacing it in a server-style app with a plain wh.WaitOne((int)mill).

Comment: Yeah I'll try it. I can always fall back on the original. I didn't want the extra dependency on System.Drawing but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is running in a service, avoid using Application.DoEvents() because, among other reasons, it requires adding a System.Windows.Forms reference.

About the comment suggesting WaitHandle.WaitOne(), I don't think it will work because it doesn't clear the Windows message pipe.

The 3 functions PeekMessage, TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage are needed because our SDK's DicomNet uses Windows messages, so you must pump the message queue to find the DICOM message intermingled with the Windows Messages. WaitHandle isn’t going to do anything with the windows message queue.

Using these three functions is the same message pump that exists in all Windows Applications, regardless of what layers of new technology get added to them over the years (like the .NET framework). It is the lowest level version and therefore the most lightweight.

If there's anything I would change, it's to use GetMessage instead of PeakMessage for the message pump. This will potentially improve performance and keep the CPU utilization down. There's a demo project that uses this approach [in this forum post](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/m15053-#post15053). The post is old, but the concept of message pump is still the same.

Note: If you're using the current version 20 of LEADTOOLS, the new [DicomNet.Breathe method](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v20/dh/di/dicomnet-breathe.html) has been added so that you don't have to use extern's. The method simply implements a standard Windows Message pump.

Comment: Yeah thanks. I knew about GetMessage. I wish lead would fix there sample code.